# Create a NETMF service and generate a WSDL file for it

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl, .net-micro-framework

We want to create a NETMF [web service that lives on a device](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826001(v=vs.85).aspx).

We have read the [MSDN Implementing Web Services on Your Devices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc533006.aspx). It explains [Generating Service Model Code Using MfSvcUtil](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd170126.aspx), which assumes that we already have a WSDL file.

How do we generate the WSDL file in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer

Create a NETMF service in C# and generate the WSDL from it.

## Steps

First, install NEFMF with DPWS. We used NETMF 4.3 with DPWS from [NETMF on Codeplex](https://netmf.codeplex.com/). This might also work with [NETMF 4.4 or later from GitHub](http://netmf.github.io/).

Second, add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Micro Framework\v4.3\Tools` to your PATH. This is a convenient way to access the `MFSvcUtil`.

Third, create a new NETMF project with a service. Here is a very simple one. You will need to reference `MFWsStack.dll` because it contains the `Ws.ServiceModel` namespace.

```
using Ws.ServiceModel;

namespace FooService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface FooService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Start();
    }
}
```

Fourth, build the project.

Fifth, run the following (which is in PowerShell) to create the WSDL file.

```
> $projectRoot = "C:\FooService\";

> $svcAssembly = ".\bin\Debug\FooService.dll";

> $library = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Micro Framework\v4.3\Assemblies\le";

> $destinationDir = ".\temp";

> $destinationFile = "FooService.wsdl";

> cd $projectRoot;

> New-Item -type dir $destinationDir;

> mfsvcutil $svcAssembly /R:$library /D:$destinationDir /O:$destinationFile

      ServiceContract = FooService
      Operation Name = Start
Writing FooService Service Description to: .\temp\FooService.wsdl
Processing complete.
```

In the above script, `library` is the directory that contains `MFWsStack.dll`, which is our project's only external reference. The script creates the WSDL file in `C:\FooService\temp\FooService.wsdl`. Hooray!